# How to write/overwrite a file with HTMLParser

Tags: python, postgresql, html-parsing, psycopg2

I need to create some files from a template. I'm using psycopg2 to fetch from a database. Then I loop through. Now I need to write to file.
Thanks!

```
import sys
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
from xml.etree import cElementTree as etree
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras

class LinksParser(HTMLParser):
  def __init__(self):
      HTMLParser.__init__(self)
      self.tb = etree.TreeBuilder()

  def handle_starttag(self, tag, attributes):
      self.tb.start(tag, dict(attributes))

  def handle_endtag(self, tag):
      self.tb.end(tag)

  def handle_data(self, data):
      self.tb.data(data)

  def close(self):
      HTMLParser.close(self)
      return self.tb.close()

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="**", user="**", password="**", host="/tmp/", port="**")
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM landingpagedata;")
rows = cur.fetchall()
template = 'template.html'

parser = LinksParser()
# parser.feed(open('landingIndex.html').read()) #for testing
# root = parser.close()

for row in rows:
    parser.feed(open(template).read())
    root = parser.close()

    #title
    title = root.find(".//title")
    title.text = str(row['title'])
    f = open(row['page_name'], 'w')
    root.write(f)
    parser = LinksParser()
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Morgan13/Programming/LandingPageBuilder/landingPages/landingBuilderTest.py", line 87, in <module>
    main()
File "/Users/Morgan13/Programming/LandingPageBuilder/landingPages/landingBuilderTest.py", line 75, in main
    root.write('page_name')
AttributeError: write
```

Oh and I'm using open('page', 'w') because these pages exist already?

Comment: When you encounter an error, always show the **full, exact error message**.

Comment: Newbie move. Fixing now.

Comment: Thanks. You haven't shown your imports either; what the heck is `LinksParser()`? What's `type(root)` ?

I'd say you need to call a method on the root element to serialise it to a string, then `f.write(...)` the resulting string.

Comment: Posted the rest. Gonna try these out. And look up how to serialize root

Comment: UGH. So I imported this: 'from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring' and 'tostring(root)' does the trick. Sorry for the shabby question. Lesson learned!!!

Comment: Please post as an answer with full explanation of the situation to help others later. BTW, it's not very good style to use `from ... import ` heavily; it's usually better to just use the modulename prefixes when invoking things, that way it's easier to understand code snippets without always referring back to the imports. It's useful when you're using an imported name a *lot*, but should be avoided if you're only referring to it a few times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `f.write(root)`, not `root.write(f)`.  (Assuming that str(root) gives you the HTML you want to write out.)

Comment: That gets me this.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Morgan13/Programming/LandingPageBuilder/landingPages/landingBuilderTest.py", line 87, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/Morgan13/Programming/LandingPageBuilder/landingPages/landingBuilderTest.py", line 75, in main
    f.write(root)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Comment: writing:
print root
gets me:
<Element 'head' at 0x10892a420>

14 times, one for each row.

Comment: writing: print root.text gets me 14 rows of white space